# CLLocationManager giving wrong updates in iOS9

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am experiencing some weird issue with CLLocationManager. My app functions on location updates, when user moves around 250m, there is something to do.

I have to show users how far are they from each other, for that i need to update location every 5 meters. I sometimes receive location updates which are 300m to 400m apart from each other. This mostly happens when i run the app for the first time. But when the last location update is thrown in the burst, it is somewhat accurate.

I am checking timestamps and horizontal accuracy of CLLocation but that is not helping out. How can I drop out these unwanted location updates?

```
    +(instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static id sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[LocationManager alloc]init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
    }

#pragma mark - Get User Location
    -(void)getUserLocation{
    if (self.locationManager==nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >=8.0) {
        // [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;

    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (fabs(howRecent) < 5.0 && manager.desiredAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyBest && location.horizontalAccuracy<=10) {

        // If the event is recent, do something with it.
        NSLog(@"New Event");
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",

              location.coordinate.latitude,

              location.coordinate.longitude);

        [[ParseManagerClass sharedInstance]saveUserLocation:location];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"cached one event");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you simulating or using a real device to test? Location update is not always guaranteed to update you for a *fixed* distance

Comment: I am testing on real device. It is not guaranteed to throw update for a fixed distance but should at least not throw updates whose difference is 300-400m.

Comment: You may want to simulate walking, and find out the exact reason why it "sometimes" does. Physical device has "physical" limitations.

Comment: Even when i am steady at one place, it gives that much difference in the locations.

Comment: That's the reason behind using simulator. For real device, the GPS location would update, while it's trying to improve the accuracy, i.e. after processing signals from more satellites, trying to use location provided by Wifi or network provider.

Comment: @zcui93 - i don't think location updates are made when you are using a simulator, however i am using a real device as i told you.

Comment: You can simulate location change by simulator.